# Complicated Knife Edge

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make an unusually shaped knife, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to model the edge and make it sharp. anyone who could help with this is appreciated. Here is the knife in edit mode.
[image: knife in edit mode]

I am attempting to model a character from my favorite show, and this is a blade on the wing.
thank you for your help, those who answer! If I need to include other information, please feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Maybe select the edge loops and scale on Z? Or show a reference image of your object and share your file?

Comment: @moonboots what do you mean by edge loops? i am a complete beginner to blender and do not know probably 98% of the functions of the program. do you mean just to select the edges and z-scale them?

Comment: Yes select the edges where you want the blade to be sharp and scale on Z, but if you show a reference image we could propose a solution

Comment: @moonboots no, that did it. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select these 2 edges (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>):

[image]

Scale on Z (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]

If you pull the middle edge it will be even sharper:

[image]